# Multiple charts on an SSRS 2012 report, rendering incorrectly on ASP.NET webpage

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm having a bizarre issue where SSRS charts placed side-by-side render properly but the report body layout goes crazy when I try to place a chart beneath the others.

This only happens with the `ReportViewer` control **(v 8.0.0.0)** in ASP.NET. When I try using the `ReportViewer` control in an C#/.NET desktop application, the report renders properly.

The `ReportViewer` control markup looks like this:

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" SizeToReportContent=True AsyncRendering=False ProcessingMode="Remote" BackColor="#E0E0E0" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" ShowBackButton="True" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" Width="100%">
     <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://ReportServer" />
  </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

And here's the problem in action:

#### Two Charts side-by-side, everything is fine

[image]

#### Three Charts side-by-side, also fine

[image]

#### However, Three charts positioned like this in the Report Builder

[image]

#### renders like this in the ReportViewer control on the web page

[image]

I've tried placing the charts in Tables, Matrixes, and Rectangles but nothing seems to help.

Can anyone shed any light on what's going on?

### Update

I don't appear to have this issue using v11.0.0.0 of the `ReportViewer` control. It's only an issue with v8 or v9.

I'm investigating just upgrading across the board but I'd still like to know if there's a workaround.

Comment: Do you get the same rendering if you access the report through the reportserver?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test that right now because I've updated the ReportViewer control the server. My suspicion is that it would have rendered incorrectly because it would have been using the same old version of the control.

Comment: Are you using ie 11+? I think there are some changes in the way it handles HTML and CSS. Anecdotally, there were some hacks in the previous versions of SSRS to get it to display correctly, which is why I believe it doesn't render in chrome very well. Perhaps try an earlier version of ie?

Comment: This issue appears to happen cross-browser. I've tested IE8, IE9, IE10 and Chrome.

Comment: did you checked read-permissions for SQLServerRS account where the Reporting Services Styles are?